# android recyclerView buffer / accumulate click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java, rx-java2

I am looking for a way to buffer / accumulate user clicks, in a way that only when the user stopped his selections of item I will trigger my action.

I tried with rx but couldn't find the best solution.

thanks for the help.

Comment: `throttle`/`debounce`? do you want to count the clicks? or just know when user stopped?

Comment: when the user stopped.. as long as he clicks on items I don't want to update anything, when he stops I would like to update, even if its only one click of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`debounce()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#debounce(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) operator.
 "when is stopped" must be defined by a range of time that no event happens that conclude that the user 'stopped' clicked. it's defined by the `timeout` param of the `debounce` operator.